# HTTP Get Method For JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I want to using http get method to retrieve back the data which is in JSON format as show in the following base on data_id 
 
Here are my JSON data

```
{
    "data_id": "61dffeaa728844adbf49eb090e4ece0e",
    "file_info": {
        "display_name": "samplefile.txt",
        "file_size": 81035,
        "file_type": "text/plain",
        "file_type_description": "ASCII text",
        "md5": "c05017f68343a5257fc3c0db72aa58dc",
        "sha1": "ba46b945f408cc729458380350b4e78f61741c81",
        "sha256": "8805777d2d561255edcb499f7445ef0216b75737bacb6bc6665dbf9830272f53",
        "upload_timestamp": "2015-08-14T12:46:59.360Z"
    },
    "scan_results": {
        "data_id": "61dffeaa728844adbf49eb090e4ece0e",
        "progress_percentage": 100,
        "scan_all_result_a": "No Threat Detected",
        "scan_all_result_i": 0,
        "scan_details": {
            "Engine1": {
                "def_time": "2015-08-13T09:32:48.000Z",
                "location": "local",
                "scan_result_i": 0,
                "scan_time": 1,
                "threat_found": ""
            },
            "Engine2": {
                "def_time": "2015-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                "location": "local",
                "scan_result_i": 0,
                "scan_time": 3,
                "threat_found": ""
            }
        },
        "start_time": "2015-08-14T12:46:59.363Z",
        "total_avs": 2,
        "total_time": 389
    },
    "process_info": {
        "post_processing": {
            "actions_ran": "",
            "actions_failed": "",
            "converted_to": "",
            "copy_move_destination": "",
            "converted_destination": ""
        },
        "progress_percentage": 100,
        "user_agent": "webscan",
        "profile": "File scan",
        "result": "Allowed",
        "blocked_reason": "",
        "file_type_skipped_scan": false
    }
}
```

According to the website documentation, I can retrieve the JSON data via http://www.example.com/file/{data_id}. But my JavaScript fail to do that and I didn't get any response to my web browser.May I know is it my JavaScript having some problem to retrieve the JSON data? I am a bit new for how JSON data work

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function formShow()
     {
      var getData = function(url, callback) {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('get', url, true);
      request.responseType = 'json';
      request.onload = function() {
      var status = request.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        callback(null, request.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  };
  getData('http://192.168.0.25:8008/file/d81d2e183dbd4303a1ffa6d8388bbd27', function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result);
    result.innerText = data.result;
  }
});
     }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="" name="myForm">
  <input type="submit" value="Show" onclick="formShow()">
</form> 
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what errors do you see in your browser developer tools console?

Comment: `getJSON` is defined in `jQuery` so please add jQuery if you want to use `getJSON` use `jQuery.getJSON` as a starting point.

Comment: you may also use native `fetch` API as described here https://davidwalsh.name/fetch if you don't want to use jQuery

Comment: I make some mistake during the posting, I had changed it to getData method, not getJSON method. No error showing in the browser developer tool, it's only show me one file successful loaded which is my html file

Comment: I see the problem - `formShow` is called as a result of a form submit (why use forms at all?) - therefore, as action is empty, you'll just end up POSTing to the current URL and probably get an error

Comment: @HeartBreakKID - so when you hit submit (Show), nothing gets shown in the developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX - when I hit submit button , nothing show up in developer tool or web browser, I had send my file to my testing virus scanning server using API call and return me an data_id, so I wish to retrieve back my result base on that data_id my idea is when the button was clicked, as least display the JSON data in the web browser, I am not sure is it a correct idea or not

Comment: so, formShow doesn't get executed, nothing happens at all ... interesting ... perhaps use a browser with a better Developer Tools Console, because clearly something should happen with that code

Comment: you create an XMLHttpRequest object named `request`, then use `xhr.send()` ... so you should at least get an error there ... but, the page will try to POST to the URL of the page itself, and your http server should .... wait, this is served through a http server, right?

Comment: @JaromandaX - this will not server through an http server, all of this being done in local PC included my virus scanning server, I had develop another set of program to send scan request and file to the server using POST method, it's return me the data_id

Comment: well, you should be getting failures in your developer tools console - which browser are you running again?

Comment: @JaromandaX - after I change the xhr.send to request.send which is my XMLHttpRequest object name, it's show me this error, please refer to the printscreen , "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DWfktIA9CjenpiQTJiaWpPUmM/view?usp=sharing" , let me if you cant open it

Comment: it should've shown you an error before ... oh, and "this error" means what exactly - doesn't matter - you'll have CORS issues ... which browser are you trying this with again?

Comment: the browser I using is chrome

Answer (score -1):

why dont you use ajax to get your response in JSON FORMAT directly...
you can achieve it by using following code..

```
$.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: getRootURL() + 'yourpath/methodPath',
        dataType: 'json', // data type of response  
        contentType:'application/json',
        success: populateAllJSONData,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            handleErrors('Error: ' , textStatus , errorThrown);
            hideLoader();   
        }
    });
```

// and then define the populateAllJSONData(data) function to display data in json format....

```
function populateAllJSONData(data)
{
   // here "data" contains your responsed JSON output....
}
```

Comment: I also search about some information about Ajax but I am very new to Ajax, is it very comfort to use ?

Comment: Don't use jQuery just because it's jQuery

Comment: i usually use ajax request to get data from database...its response is fast ans easy to use...